# My Java code is not running

Tags: java

If I am not mistaken, this bit of code should print out all even numbers smaller than or equal to 100. When I run this code, nothing happens. No error message or anything. I'm using Eclipse.

```
public class Even {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int number = 1;
        int remainder = number % 2;

        while(number <= 100) {
            number++;
            if(remainder == 0) {
                System.out.println(number);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `remainder` never changes.

Comment: `int remainder = number % 2;` before the loop, the value of `remainder` is 1 and never changes afterwards. The print statement is never executed.

Comment: I'm not surprised. `remainder` is 1, and stays as 1...

Comment: You need to update 'remainder' in the loop. Otherwise remainder == 0 is never true.

Comment: you are mistaken

Comment: As an aside, now would be a good time to learn to use a debugger - step through the code line by line, work out where it's not behaving as you expect it to. I suspect that by the time you've been through the loop a few times, you'll see why it's not working. Debugging is a really important skill.

Comment: Huh? Why do I need to update remainder? I'm increasing number by one in the loop which should bring int number up to 2, making the remainder 0, right? Sorry if I'm sounding dumb. I'm still learning.

Comment: You are confusing the mathematical remainder with the variable `remainder`.  While it's true that increasing the value of `number` will change the remainder when divided by 2, the value of the variable `remainder` is only changed if and when you change it.

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others stated before, value of `remainder` is set only once. However, you check it a hundred times expecting it to tell you something else every time. I'd suggest putting it inside a loop, so you get a "fresh" value for every `number`.

```
public class Even {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    int number = 1;
    int remainder;

    while(number <= 100) {
        number++;
        remainder = number % 2;
        if(remainder == 0) {
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reminder doesn't change as the assignment is prior to while loop. The statement int remainder = number % 2; has to be inside while loop to see the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for(int i = 0;i<=100; i= i+2)
        System.out.println(i);
```

You do not need remainder :)